# Properly shutdown k3s on local machine

Tags: kubernetes

I've just installed k3s on my notebook (Ubuntu). Works fine. Great project. However, i do not need it to run 24/7 so, how do I properly shutdown the k3s cluster. Oddly, I cannot find anything about this in the documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a systemd shutdown task (`/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service`) which stops the server, but not the k8s resources (pods, networks, etc). For this there is a utility script `k3s-killall.sh` which should be at `/usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh`

Comment: On Ubuntu you can stop the k3s service with `sudo systemctl stop k3s`, and stop it restarting when you reboot with `sudo systemctl disable k3s`.